# D3 Axis Scales Not Working Properly

Tags: d3.js, axis

I'm having issue getting the axis scales to work in this chart. I've managed to get the scale to work with the 'initialBar' element, but beyond that it's not quite taking effect. I noticed when using console.log for each element in the 'initial graph' and 'updated graph' phases that the results were coming out as arrays, not values. So I added d3.max to each to get an actual number, which works now but it won't let me apply the same concept to the 'updated' charts.

In addition, you can see that the width of the svg is supposed to be 500px but no matter what I do to the width or scale settings, it's only going up to 300px. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

Script:

```
d3.tsv("/DOL_data.tsv", function (data) {

    //Set scales & ranges
    var width = 500;
    var height = 50;
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return 30 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN)})])
        //.domain([0,66])
        .range([0,width])

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height',height);
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xAxis').call(xAxis);

    var barText = function (d) { return d3.format("($.0f")(1 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN));};
    var targetText = function (d) { return d3.format("($.0f")(21 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN));};

    //Data aggregation
    var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d) {return d.STATE;})
      .entries(data);

    //Create dropdown
    var stateList = d3.select('#dropdown')
    .append('select')
    .attr('class','select')
    .on('change',onchange);

    var options = stateList
    .selectAll('option')
    .data(nest).enter().append('option')
    .attr('value', function (d) {return d.key;})
    .text(function (d) {return d.key});

    //Create initial graph
    var initialGraph = function (state) {

        var selectState = nest.filter(function (d) { return d.key == state;})
        var selectStateGroupsB = svg.selectAll('.wageBar')
          .data(selectState, function (d) { return d ? d.key : this.key;})
          .enter().append('g').attr("class", "wageBar")
        var selectStateGroupsL = svg.selectAll('.wageLine')
          .data(selectState, function (d) { return d ? d.key : this.key;})
          .enter().append('g').attr("class", "wageLine")
    ;

    var initialBar = selectStateGroupsB.selectAll('.rect')
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).enter().append('rect')
            .attr('height', height)
            .attr('width', function(d){return x(parseFloat(d3.max(d.H_MEAN))); })
            .attr('fill', '#38ACEC')
            .attr('x',0)
            .attr('y',0);

            console.log(d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.H_MEAN}));

        var initialLine = selectStateGroupsL.selectAll('.line')
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).enter().append('line')
            .attr('stroke','#444444')
            .attr('stroke-width',4)
            .attr('x1', function (d) { return x(20 + parseFloat(d3.max(d.H_MEAN)));})
            .attr('x2', function (d) { return x(20 + parseFloat(d3.max(d.H_MEAN)));})
            .attr('y1',0)
            .attr('y2',height);

        var initialBarText = selectStateGroupsB.selectAll('.text')
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).enter().append('text')
            .text(barText)
            .attr('y',height/2).attr('x', function(d){return x(1 + parseFloat(d3.max(d.H_MEAN)));})
            .attr('alignment-baseline', 'central')
            .attr('font-family', 'Arial').attr('font-size', '10px').attr('alignment-baseline','central');

        var initialLineText = selectStateGroupsL.selectAll('.text')
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).enter().append('text')
            .text(targetText)
            .attr('y',height/2).attr('x', function(d){return x(21 + parseFloat(d3.max(d.H_MEAN)))})
            .attr('font-family', 'Arial').attr('font-size', '10px').attr('alignment-baseline','central');
    }

    initialGraph('Alabama');

    //Update graph
    var updateGraph = function(state) {
        var selectState = nest.filter(function (d) { return d.key == state;})
        var selectStateGroupsB = svg.selectAll('.wageBar')
            .data(selectState);
        var selectStateGroupsL = svg.selectAll('.wageLine')
            .data(selectState);

        selectStateGroupsB.selectAll('rect')
             .data(function(d){return (d.values);}).transition().duration(1000)
             .attr('width',function(d) {return x(d.H_MEAN); });

        selectStateGroupsL.selectAll('line')
                .data(function (d) { return (d.values); }).transition().duration(1000)
                .attr('x1',function (d) { return x(20 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN))})
                .attr('x2',function (d) { return x(20 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN))});

        selectStateGroupsB.selectAll('text')
                .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).transition().duration(1000)
                .text(barText)
                .attr('y',height/2).attr('x', function(d) {return x(1 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN))})
                .attr('font-family', 'Arial').attr('font-size', '10px').attr('alignment-baseline','central');

        selectStateGroupsL.selectAll('text')
                .data(function (d) { return d.values; }).transition().duration(1000)
                .text(targetText)
                .attr('y',height/2).attr('x',function(d){return x(21 + parseFloat(d.H_MEAN))})
                .attr('font-family', 'Arial').attr('font-size', '10px').attr('alignment-baseline','central');
    }

    function onchange() {
        var selectedState = d3.select('select').property('value');
        updateGraph(selectedState);
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
  body {
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
  }

.xAxis { display: none;};

</style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='chart.js'></script>
  <div id="dropdown" div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sample Data:

```
AREA    ST  STATE   OCC_CODE    OCC_TITLE   OCC_GROUP   TOT_EMP EMP_PRSE    JOBS_1000   LOC_Q   H_MEAN  A_MEAN  MEAN_PRSE   H_PCT10 H_PCT25 H_MEDIAN    H_PCT75 H_PCT90 A_PCT10 A_PCT25 A_MEDIAN    A_PCT75 A_PCT90
01  AL  Alabama 29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    49,290  1.4 25.638  1.26    27.83   57,890  0.5 20.14   22.82   27.20   31.71   37.40   41,890  47,470  56,570  65,950  77,790
02  AK  Alaska  29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    5,570   3.8 17.504  0.86    42.07   87,510  2.1 29.94   34.63   41.45   49.00   57.31   62,270  72,030  86,220  101,910 119,210
04  AZ  Arizona 29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    54,630  2.9 20.203  0.99    36.11   75,110  0.8 26.14   30.64   35.70   41.69   47.76   54,370  63,720  74,260  86,720  99,350
05  AR  Arkansas    29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    24,380  4.0 20.318  1.00    28.28   58,810  1.3 20.06   23.13   27.68   32.88   37.97   41,730  48,100  57,570  68,400  78,980
06  CA  California  29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    282,290 1.7 16.908  0.83    49.37   102,700 0.8 30.98   38.56   48.43   60.30   72.70   64,430  80,210  100,730 125,430 151,210
08  CO  Colorado    29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    49,340  1.7 19.309  0.95    34.89   72,570  0.6 25.67   28.89   34.27   40.19   47.02   53,390  60,100  71,280  83,600  97,810
09  CT  Connecticut 29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    34,310  7.7 20.741  1.02    38.56   80,200  1.0 27.58   32.71   38.22   45.21   49.77   57,360  68,040  79,500  94,030  103,520
10  DE  Delaware    29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    11,620  2.8 26.246  1.29    35.18   73,180  1.9 26.13   29.44   34.43   39.26   47.08   54,350  61,240  71,610  81,660  97,930
11  DC  District of Columbia    29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    11,000  2.4 15.539  0.76    43.32   90,110  5.1 27.53   33.54   41.85   49.44   61.92   57,270  69,760  87,040  102,840 128,790
12  FL  Florida 29-1141 Registered Nurses   detailed    178,330 2.1 21.182  1.04    31.20   64,890  0.6 22.51   26.36   30.32   36.12   40.64   46,830  54,840  63,060  75,130  84,530
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove the `display:none` of the xAxis, no `;` at end of css

  ```
  .xAxis { display: none;};

  .xAxis {}
  ```
- add a width attribute to your svg

  ```
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height',height).attr('width', width);
  ```
- translate the x-axis

  ```
  svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate(0,50)').attr('class', 'xAxis').call(xAxis);
  ```
- make the svg bigger and define a height for the bars

  ```
  var width = 500;
  var height = 100;
  var heightBar = 50;
  ```
- replace many references of `height` to `heightBar`
- fix your input because what you post is not a TSV, and DC has 2 numbers extra (why?)
- fix the `div#dropdown` (no close tag) and what is the attribute `div`

  ```
  <div id="dropdown" div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! To answer your question - the file itself is actually TSV, but I just opened it in whatever native application would open it this afternoon and that's the format it displayed in, so I just copy and pasted - sorry for the confusion. Again, thanks SO much - this was a huge help.

Comment: Oh, also I wanted the axis line and ticks hidden; was just concerned about getting the scales to work.